In wireless power transfer coil characterization what is the significance of resistance of the transmitter coil at resonance frequency
I am characterizing a wireless transfer coil with the help of this document from Omicron.
In page no no-7 you can see that they are finding the resistance of the coil at resonance and it's value is 9.304 kΩ.
May I know the significance or impact of this resistance in wireless power transfer.
I believe it has no significance, they are just finding the resonance frequency for other calculations. Please correct me if I am wrong.


May I know the significance or impact of this resistance in wireless
power transfer.

At self-resonance (8.5 MHz) they are measuring the equivalent parallel resistance (EPR) of the coil and then they are calculating the self-capacitance of the coil (14.92 pF). EPR is a figure of merit for the coil because, a high EPR is indicative of a lower realistic effective series resistance (ESR) when driven at the normal coupling frequency of 125 kHz.
A lower ESR means a bigger transmit magnetic field and, the ability to couple energy to more distant receive coils. Note that a page later they go on to show the ESR as being 0.212 Ω.
So, EPR and ESR go hand in hand. If ESR lowers, EPR goes up.

When EPR is 9.3K the ESR is 212m Ohm and when EPR is 17.17K the ESR is 262m Ohm (Page no 9 and 10 for RX Coil).Can I say ESR increases with EPR

You can't make comparisons between transmit and receiver coil. The receiver coil has a higher self-resonant frequency and that makes all the difference. It's a figure of merit for a particular coil design. For a specific coil design ESR falls with EPR rising.

Thank you.  EPR = Q^2ESR, Higher EPR means higher Q and lower the loss and high efficency.Correct me if I am wrong.

That formula looks about right but, I'm on a phone now so can't double check this. Maybe leave a link to where you got the formula @Confused

https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Electrical_Engineering/Electronics/AC_Electrical_Circuit_Analysis%3A_A_Practical_Approach_(Fiore)/08%3A_Resonance/8.3%3A_Parallel_Resonance

Yes, I have checked that formula and it is correct. However, if you don't know what the external induction losses are due to eddy currents you will get a much higher value for the EPR because, the formula cannot know what those losses are. Additionally, the true ESR at 8.5 MHz will be significantly more than the ESR at 125 kHz due to winding skin effect and, this can cause an error effect on that formula.

Ho will calculate the ESR at 125 kHz

Not sure what you mean.

" the true ESR at 8.5 MHz will be significantly more than the ESR at 125 kHz due to winding skin effect"I mean in the appnote they are calculating ESR at 8.5Mhz.The frequency of interest is 125Khz.May I know any method to calculate ESR at 125Khz

No, @Confused they are measuring ESR at 125 kHz.
